# Using R and gsub is there a way to remove two special characters and replace with one

Tags: r, special-characters, gsub

I want to remove two special characters from the vector in one line of code

```
 col1<-c("0;13:14"  "0:12\"22")
```

I don't want to do this though it works

```
df$Col1<- 
  gsub(";",":",df$Col1)

df$Col1<- 
  gsub("\",":",df$Col1)
```

Is there a way to replace ";" or "" with ":" in one gsub line?

Comment: `gsub("[\\:]",":",df$Col1)` or `gsub("[\\\\:]",":",df$Col1, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Error: '\;' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""[\;"

Comment: Double the backslash, see https://ideone.com/dhCRf0. BTW, `"0:12\"22"` has bo backslash. It has a `"` inside, `0:12"22`. So, you probably *actually* need `gsub("[\":]",":", col1)`, see https://ideone.com/ysjLvo